# plotly area chart, how can I set fill opacity?

Tags: python, plotly

The code below is copied from plotly tutorial https://plot.ly/python/filled-area-plots/, except the line with `opacity` setting.

However, this doesn't work. How can I set the opacity of the filled area?

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# Add original data
x = ['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall']

trace0 = dict(
    x=x,
    y=[40, 60, 40, 10],
    hoverinfo='x+y',
    mode='lines',
    ##########
    opacity = 0.5,
    ##########
    line=dict(width=0.5,
              color='rgb(131, 90, 241)'),
    stackgroup='one'
)
trace1 = dict(
    x=x,
    y=[20, 10, 10, 60],
    hoverinfo='x+y',
    mode='lines',
    ##########
    opacity = 0.5,
    ##########
    line=dict(width=0.5,
              color='rgb(111, 231, 219)'),
    stackgroup='one'
)
trace2 = dict(
    x=x,
    y=[40, 30, 50, 30],
    hoverinfo='x+y',
    mode='lines',
    ##########
    opacity = 0.5,
    ##########
    line=dict(width=0.5,
              color='rgb(184, 247, 212)'),
    stackgroup='one'
)
data = [trace0, trace1, trace2]

fig = dict(data=data)
py.iplot(fig, filename='stacked-area-plot-hover', validate=False)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the opacity in a filled area plot by providing a RGBA color in `fillcolor`, e.g.

```
import plotly.plotly as py

x = ['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall']

y_values = [[40, 60, 40, 10],
            [20, 10, 10, 60],
            [40, 30, 50, 30]]

colors = ['rgba(131, 90, 241, 0.25)',
          'rgba(111, 231, 219, 0.5)',
          'rgba(184, 247, 212, 1)']

data = []

for i, y in enumerate(y_values):
    data.append(dict(x=x,
                     y=y,
                     hoverinfo='x+y',
                     mode='lines',
                     line=dict(width=0.5,
                               color=colors[i]),
                     fillcolor=colors[i],
                     stackgroup='one'))
          


fig = dict(data=data)
py.iplot(fig, filename='stacked-area-plot-hover', validate=False)
```

gives you

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to set opacity without a list of colors?

Comment: Do you want to use the default colors and just modify the opacity?

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, yes, yes

Comment: @Soren: You can set the opacity for lines and markers but for area charts I didn't find an obvious way of providing opacity without colors.

Answer (score 2):

As of today (2023-01-20), there is no way to change the fill color opacity without explicitly declaring the color with `fillcolor`.

There is an open issue in Plotly's GitHub repository: [#3344 - fillcolor opacity attribute](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3344), although it didn't get much attention in the last years, so I would not hold my breath.